# Convert json numbers to strings in the shell

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, json

When parsing *json*, the command-line tool `jshon` converts numbers to scientific notation, and sometimes [tries to round them](https://github.com/keenerd/jshon/issues/19).

To avoid these problems, I want jshon to consider these numbers as strings. For that, I have found that I need to place quotes around all numbers in the json file. After some unsuccessful googling, I have tried writing a sed command to quote the numbers, but I found it pretty unsafe, and have run into lots of issues already:

```
 sed -r 's/(" ?[:,] ?)"?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)"?([,}]|$)/\1"\2"\4/g' $file
```

I would like to know if there is some stable **parser** that can give me the desired result. I'm not including an example json file in the question, because I need this code for some little risky operations, and I will be parsing json from random websites.

Comment: I think that you are looking for a json parser here, you sure you want to use sed? It will be messy and error prone.

Comment: @Braiam that was specified in the question.

Comment: you want [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: @mikeserv I have tried their **Try online!** and, unfortunately, it converts the numbers to scientific notation and also rounds large numbers.

Comment: Get the download, pipe the output as strings into `bc` or `dc` and what you want then back. Else, get `node.js`.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks, but I don't understand! Here are two numbers that give undesired results in their **Try online!**: `{"a":200.12345678999999, "b":0.00001875}`

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, but I don't have the time to demo. Can you try `node.js`?

Comment: @mikeserv I'm going to study it.

Comment: Best of luck, @TeresaeJunior.

Comment: @mikeserv `node.js` requires me to learn Javascript. I would still be safer using `sed`, since I only know bash :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple python3 script you can call as a filter in a shell. Save the script below in a file named something like `filter.py`, make executable, and call with `./filter.py <$file`

Since I don't know the structure of your JSON file, I assume one json string per line. Let me know if you need it tweaked.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import json
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
   try:
       print(json.dumps(json.loads(line, parse_float=str)))
   except (ValueError, TypeError):
       pass  # skip lines not parsable by json
       # print(line)  # uncomment to print non-json lines as-is
   # uncomment to ignore all other errors
   # except Exception:
   #    pass
exit(0)
```

Here is the output of my tests:

```
$ cat $file
{"a":200.12345678999999, "b":0.00001875}
{"a":200.1234567893029999, "b":0.03091875}
$ ./test.py <$file
{"a": "200.12345678999999", "b": "0.00001875"}
{"a": "200.1234567893029999", "b": "0.03091875"}
```

Comment: This is really great! I have also found that the *janson* lib used by *jshon* has problems parsing long integers, so I replaced `parse_float=str` with `parse_int=str, parse_float=str`. That's a lot of problems with *janson*, maybe I should have `jq` a better look!

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with any json library in particular, but with [floating point rounding errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error) native to the processor. I'm not sure about long integers, but I would guess it is a similar issue.